# How can I retrieve multiple child objects in React asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, state

I'm putting together a project in React where I need to create an array of objects in the state of a parent object from a set of child objects each containing info that gets passed to the parent. My problem is that on initialization, because each of the child objects are getting created at what is basically the exact same time, the parent object's update function overwrites what the previous children had given it instead of adding their info to the array. Eventually I'm going to be translating this into typescript, but for now a basic implementation in standard JS demonstrates the point.

Parent.jsx:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { useState } from 'react';

import Child from './_Child';

const Parent = () => {
  // State where we should have the objects from 
  const [childObjects, setChildObjects] = useState([]);

  // Updater function to pass to children
  const updateNameInParent = async (myObj) => {
    const objectsClone = _.cloneDeep(childObjects);
    const newObj = [...objectsClone, myObj];
    setChildObjects(newObj);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My child objects are {childObjects.join(',')}</h1>
      <ul>
        <Child action={updateNameInParent} name='Child One!' />
        <Child action={updateNameInParent} name='Child Two!' />
        <Child action={updateNameInParent} name='Child Three!' />
        <Child action={updateNameInParent} name='Child Four!' />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const child = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Hello, I am the child ' + props.name);
    props.action(props.name);
  }, [])

  return <li>{props.name}</li>;
}

export default child;
```

Expected Behavior:

Parent object's  text to be "My child objects are Child One, Child Two, Child Three, Child Four!"

Actual Behavior:

Parent object's  text is "My child objects are Child Four" as child one is overwritten by child two, child two by child three, and child three by child four.

Note: Order of objects won't actually matter in the end product for me, just looking to get functionality up and running.

Included Repl to demonstrate this live:

https://replit.com/@saintjustin/DrySnarlingCones

Comment: Btw, why do you need deepClone here? I think is unnecessary here.

Comment: It's not necessary for the implementation I showed here, but it's a safety precaution that I'll need in the final implementation of this pattern. This demo is pretty abstracted from the source code (as it's currently ~2000 lines of spaghetti).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the callback version of the `setChildObjects` which guarantees to have the latest data.

```
  // Updater function to pass to children
  const updateNameInParent = useCallback(async (myObj) => {
    setChildObjects((currentChildObjects) => {
      const objectsClone = _.cloneDeep(currentChildObjects);
      return [...objectsClone, myObj];
    });
  }, []);
```

and you should use `useCallback` to avoid creating new function for each re-render and causing all children to re-render due to receiving a new prop.

Comment: That worked like a charm! Just to make sure, will utilizing useCallback will still force an update for children who's props change as a result of the callback?

Comment: The `useCallback` (*with the latest edit of adding `[]` as the dependencies list, in my answer*) will guarantee that the `updateNameInParent` function will stay the same between re-renders of the `Parent` component.